# how can i solve this error in git if I am push repositary form githum.com

Tags: git, github

The error looks like this

```
ssh: connect to host githum.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How can I fix and avoid this error?

Comment: Did you mean to connect to github?

Comment: It should be githu**b**.com

Comment: `git remote add origin your repository` http://github.com/yourrepository

Answer (score 1):

To fix the typo (github, not githum) while still using the SSH URL, you can:

- first [check if your SSH key is properly registered](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection):

  ```
    ssh -Tv git@github.com
  ```

You should see:

```
Hi <me>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```

If not, see "[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)"

- then change the remote origin URL in your local repository:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
git push -u origin main
```